# Basic Java: While loop for basic quiz?

Tags: java, while-loop

I started learning Java last night, and I'm trying to make my first code without it being dictated to me!

It is a simple quiz question that asks the user "Do you think my dog is cute?" If they answer "Yes," the dog Woofs and smiles. If they say "no" He growls at them and frowns.
If a different answer is given, "What? Please try again" is printed.

I have no issue getting this working so far, but now I am trying to make it so that when an unrecognised answer is put in, the question is asked again, and this repeats until they answer either "Yes" or "No." Here is what I have tried:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CopyOfMain {
    public static void main(String joel[]){
        System.out.println("Do you think my dog Olly is cute? Yes or No");
        Scanner ans = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Ans = ans.nextLine();
        while (!Ans.equals("Yes") || !Ans.equals("No")); {
            if (Ans.equals("Yes")){
                System.out.print("Woof :-)");

            }else if(Ans.equals("No")){
                System.out.print("Grrrr :-(");

            }else{  
                System.out.print("What? Please try again.");
            }   
        }
    ans.close();
    }
}
```

All I have added to the working code is the while loop, but now if "Yes" or "No" is entered, there is no printed woof or growl. However, if something other than "Yes" or "No" is entered, the correct words and printed, but the question is still not re-asked.
Could someone please suggest a fix?

Comment: `while (!Ans.equals("Yes") || !Ans.equals("No")); {` what is `;` doing there? Also lets use math analogy: can you show some number `x` which would not fulfil this condition `(x != 1) || (x != 2)`?

Comment: Ah! That is one of the issues. 

Funnily enough, that stemmed from me trying to write
!Ans.equals("Yes" || "No"), then I realised you can't do that, so I split it up, and forgot to change the ||!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-read the line in the loop (also use an AND not an OR nothing is both "Yes" and "No" **or** an the simpler infinite loop and break), also - I would use another variable `Ans` and `ans` are too similar for my tastes, Additionally, note that I'm testing your strings independent of case (I assume "yes" and "YES" should also work). Finally, no semicolon after `while` and before the open bracket (that makes an empty loop) -

```
String response = ans.nextLine();
while (true) {
  if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
    System.out.println("Woof :-)");
    break;
  }else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("No")){
    System.out.println("Grrrr :-(");
    break;
  }else{  
    System.out.println("What? Please try again.");
    response = ans.nextLine();
  }   
}
```

Comment: This has solved half the problem! Now when random characters are input, it asks the question again. However, when the correct answer it put it, it still returns nothing... any ideas?

Thanks for your help so far, and fast response :)

Comment: @user3780342 Edited. I missed a defect.

Comment: Thanks for editing that! I did come up with a workaround but it made my code much longer than yours, so this helps a lot!

Can I please double check that I understand what you did,
So you told it that while it's true, I.e the code is still continuing, (no break) the loop will continue cycling?

So that means the bug was that when the correct answer was put in, the loop kept cycling? Sorry for my very bad understanding, I'm still trying to work all this out!

Comment: The bug was simple, when the correct answer was put in the loop stopped before testing the if else logic. Breaking an infinite loop seems cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be able to check the result first, then check for the loop condition:

```
String Ans;

do {
    Ans = ans.nextLine()

    if (Ans.equals("Yes")) {
        System.out.print("Woof :-)");
    } else if(Ans.equals("No")) {
        System.out.print("Grrrr :-(");
    } else {  
        System.out.print("What? Please try again.");
    }
} while (!(Ans.equals("Yes") || Ans.equals("No")));
```

Comment: No, this will not work like you think. We need input.

Comment: `Not "Yes" or Not "No"` => `Not ("Yes" and "No")` => `True`

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop will always evaluate to true. If you enter "Yes", then it's not "No", and vice-versa.

When exactly do you want the while loop to be true? Say it out loud and write it down on a piece of paper before trying to work out the boolean logic.

You also need to read the answer again inside the while loop, otherwise it will never change.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! via combination of the two good answers. I used the code from this answer, and incorporated do..while from the other answer. Then I made a new If and else if statement under the existing "else" statement! Thankyou everyone for your kind and speedy help.

P.s any easier way than two seperate if/else statements?

I will put my final code here for anyone who has a similar question to me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CopyOfMain {
    public static void main(String joel[]){
        System.out.println("Do you think my dog Olly is cute? Yes or No");
        Scanner ans = new Scanner(System.in);
        String response = ans.nextLine();

        {
        do  {
            if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
                System.out.print("Woof :-)");

            }else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("No")){
                System.out.print("Grrrr :-(");

            }else{  
                System.out.print("What? Please try again.");
                response = ans.nextLine();
                if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
                    System.out.print("Woof :-)");

                }else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("No")){
                    System.out.print("Grrrr :-(");
                }
            }
          }  while (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") && !response.equalsIgnoreCase("No")); 
        }
        ans.close();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Elliot Frisch has solved the problem well, with a shorter code. Look at his edited answer!

Answer (score 0):

The most concise way of going about this would probably be a multidimensional array. Think of it as an array inside of an array.

`String arr[] =  [["question","answer"], ["question","answer"]];` ...etc

Using this method you only need one small loop:

```
for (x=0;questions < arr.length; x++) {
System.out.print(arr[x][x]);

if (arr[x][x+1] == true)
score++;

else...


}
```